# How to add CORS middleware with auth:api passport middleware in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, cors, laravel-passport

I have used Laravel Passport for authenticated endpoints. I am facing CORS issue for those APIs.

In app/Http/Middleware/Cors.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Cors
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*")
                ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', "PUT,POST,DELETE,GET,OPTIONS")
                ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', "Accept,Authorization,Content-Type");
    }
}
```

In app/Http/Kernel.php, added in the middleware array

```
\App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
```

In the routes/api.php,

```
Route::post('auth/login', 'PassportController@login'); //working 
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {
Route::get('vehicle/all', 'VehicleController@getVehicles'); //not working: facing CORS error
});
```

**I have used the auth:api (Laravel passport) for authorization. I am facing CORS error for the endpoints in the auth:api group. Endpoints which are outside the group like 'auth/login' are working fine.
How to handle cors error inside Route::middleware('auth:api') group?**

Comment: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*" is not accepted by browsers anymore, you need to specify the domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the domain allowed, the wildcard '*' is not accepted by browsers anymore.

If you have multiple domains calling your api, you can make it dynamic with `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Cors
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $domain = $request->getHost();
        // or $domain =  $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', $domain)
                ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', "PUT,POST,DELETE,GET,OPTIONS")
                ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', "Accept,Authorization,Content-Type");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @N69S. Problem solved. I have directly put domain url in $domain and modified Access-Control-Allow-Headers...

header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', "Accept,Authorization,Content-Type,Access-Control-Allow-Headers,access-control-allow-methods");

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue and the solutions found here didn't work for me.

I've simply installed the package [CORS Middleware for Laravel](https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors) and followed the [documentation](https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors#global-usage) to finally added the routes where the cors middleware should be applied to. And it worked :)

Here are the steps :

Step 1: Install the package

`composer require fruitcake/laravel-cors`

Step 2:

> To allow CORS for all your routes, add the HandleCors middleware at
> the top of the $middleware property of `app/Http/Kernel.php` class:
>
> ```
> protected $middleware = [
>   \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
>     // ...
> ];
> ```

Step 3: Publish the configuration file

> The defaults are set in `config/cors.php`. Publish the config to copy
> the file to your own config:
>
> `php artisan vendor:publish --tag="cors"`

Step 4: Update your `config/cors.php`

> Now update the config to define the paths you want to run the CORS
> service on, (see Configuration below):
>
> `'paths' => ['api/*']`,

Hope this will help you too.